# Haskell: Bizzare instance declaration in SDL bindings

Tags: haskell, sdl

The Haskell SDL bindings export an enumerated type called SDLKey.  The Enum instance is declared in a strange way though:

```
instance Enum SDLKey Word32 where
    fromEnum SDLK_UNKNOWN = 0
    fromEnum SDLK_FIRST = 0
    fromEnum SDLK_BACKSPACE = 8
    ...
```

SDLKey does not take any type parameters, how is this not a syntax error?  Haskell reports that SDLKey is not an instance of Enum, so for what type are the Enum functions being defined?  And, most importantly, given an SDLKey, how can I invoke the Enum functions on it?

Source code from hackage here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SDL/0.6.2/doc/html/src/Graphics-UI-SDL-Keysym.html#SDLKey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an instance of Enum from the Prelude (see `import Prelude hiding (Enum(..))` near the top of the file).

It is an instance of [Enum from Graphics.UI.SDL.Utilities](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SDL/0.6.2/doc/html/src/Graphics-UI-SDL-Utilities.html#Enum), which takes a second parameter:

```
class Enum a b | a -> b where
  succ :: a -> a
  pred :: a -> a
  toEnum :: b -> a
  fromEnum :: a -> b
  enumFromTo :: a -> a -> [a]
```

Compare to the definition from the Prelude:

```
class  Enum a   where
    succ                :: a -> a
    pred                :: a -> a
    toEnum              :: Int -> a
    fromEnum            :: a -> Int
    enumFrom            :: a -> [a]
    enumFromThen        :: a -> a -> [a]
    enumFromTo          :: a -> a -> [a]
    enumFromThenTo      :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
    -- comments and default definitions elided
```